# Android pairing to custom USB bluetooth adapter

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluez

Is it possible to force a legacy fixed pin entry when pairing an android to a custom USB adapter, such as the DKBT111. Looking at SSP and the "Just works" pairing, this doesn't seem to satisfy the security requirement I am working with.

I would like to guarantee no one can attempt to pair with the USB device while it is discoverable without a fixed, preset PIN. I am having trouble configuring the controller using bluetoothctl and Bluez. The best I can get is the 6 digit passkey comparison, but I won't have a display for the code on the box the usb will be connected to.

What settings do I have to change to be able to set a PIN for the server, and any phone needs to type it in to pair?

I am using Bluez on tinycore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve such scenario you may need to implement custom agent. As you don't have Display, you have to choose one of the capability of your device from the [options](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/agent-api.txt#n33).

Bluez always expects minimum 6 digit PIN key, if you want to restrict yourself to 4 digit PIN, then you should pad using "0"'s as specified [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/agent-api.txt#n108).

For your custom agent, you need to implement either "[DisplayPinCode](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/agent-api.txt#n91)" or "[DisplayPasskey](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/agent-api.txt#n126)" method returning fixed PIN and registering it using "[RegisterAgent](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/agent-api.txt#n12)".

For restricting only your Android device, you can compare your device MAC address in DisplayPinCode/DisplayPasskey, which gets the MAC address of the device which is requesting pairing as "First Argument **object device**".

Note that the "object device" is MAC address as object path i.e /org/bluez/hciX/dev_AA_BB_CC_XX_YY_ZZ format.

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include "agent.h"

#define AGENT_PATH  "/org/bluez/AutoPinAgent"

static void bluez_agent_method_call(GDBusConnection *conn,
                    const gchar *sender,
                    const gchar *path,
                    const gchar *interface,
                    const gchar *method,
                    GVariant *params,
                    GDBusMethodInvocation *invocation,
                    void *userdata)
{
    g_print("Agent method call: %s.%s()", interface, method);
}

static const GDBusInterfaceVTable agent_method_table = {
    .method_call = bluez_agent_method_call,
};

int bluez_register_agent(GDBusConnection *con)
{
    GError *error = NULL;
    guint id = 0;
    GDBusNodeInfo *info = NULL;

    static const gchar bluez_agent_introspection_xml[] =
        "<node name='/org/bluez/SampleAgent'>"
        "   <interface name='org.bluez.Agent1'>"
        "       <method name='Release'>"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='RequestPinCode'>"
        "           <arg type='o' name='device' direction='in' />"
        "           <arg type='s' name='pincode' direction='out' />"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='DisplayPinCode'>"
        "           <arg type='o' name='device' direction='in' />"
        "           <arg type='s' name='pincode' direction='in' />"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='RequestPasskey'>"
        "           <arg type='o' name='device' direction='in' />"
        "           <arg type='u' name='passkey' direction='out' />"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='DisplayPasskey'>"
        "           <arg type='o' name='device' direction='in' />"
        "           <arg type='u' name='passkey' direction='in' />"
        "           <arg type='q' name='entered' direction='in' />"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='RequestConfirmation'>"
        "           <arg type='o' name='device' direction='in' />"
        "           <arg type='u' name='passkey' direction='in' />"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='RequestAuthorization'>"
        "           <arg type='o' name='device' direction='in' />"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='AuthorizeService'>"
        "           <arg type='o' name='device' direction='in' />"
        "           <arg type='s' name='uuid' direction='in' />"
        "       </method>"
        "       <method name='Cancel'>"
        "       </method>"
        "   </interface>"
        "</node>";

    info = g_dbus_node_info_new_for_xml(bluez_agent_introspection_xml, &error);
    if(error) {
        g_printerr("Unable to create node: %s\n", error->message);
        g_clear_error(&error);
        return 0;
    }

    id = g_dbus_connection_register_object(con, 
            AGENT_PATH,
            info->interfaces[0],
            &agent_method_table,
            NULL, NULL, &error);
    g_dbus_node_info_unref(info);
    //g_dbus_connection_unregister_object(con, id);
    return id;
}
```

The above example is incomplete template without any specific methods. You need to implement "DisplayPinCode/DisplayPasskey" inside "bluez_agent_method_call" based on "method" name, which comes as argument.

**EDIT:** Same example for Fixed PIN with more details answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52142828/how-can-bluez-be-configured-to-require-a-connecting-device-to-enter-a-matching-p/52203098#52203098). Adding it for future reference and completeness.